# Time Synchronization using NetRemoteTOD in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, time, synchronization

I use NetRemoteTOD() for time synchronization with remote PC. As I understand it requires at least basic permissions from client to access that remote PC. If I just execute NetRemoteTOD(), it gives me Error 5 (Access denied). But when I connect to other PC/Server with no log in credentials it works perfectly.

and here my reference of [Time Synchronization using netRemoteTOD](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5793/Retrieving-date-and-time-from-remote-server-using)

**BTW**, it's a **WINFORM Application**.

**Question is** - `How to login to remote PC programmatically?`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the docs for [`NetRemoteTOD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370612.aspx) and this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249716) there is no indication that permissions are needed to obtain the time from the server. However you do need permission to change the time on the local machine (elevated administrators have the necessary `SeSystemtimePrivilege` privilege). Is the permission denied from setting the time?

Comment: @Richard: Thank you for your quick response. Yes, I get permission denied for accessing that certain server/pc, but when I connect to other PC without log in credentials it gets the time of that PC perfectly. Will you please explain it in a broader sir? how does **SeSystemtimePrivilege ** works?

Comment: Quick answer: you need to be an elevated administrator to set the time of a Windows machine (`SeSystemtimePrivilege` is the name of the specific privilege in the system that grants the ability to set the time).

Comment: @richar: Is this what are saying for? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113557-date-time-allow-prevent-users-groups-changing.html

Comment: Broadly yes: that is showing how to change which users and/or groups have that privilege.